# Erro na conversão do matlab para python

Tags: python, matlab

pretendo converter a seguinte função em matlab para python:

```
Função Matlab
cn = reshape(repmat(sn, n_rep, 1), 1,[]);

resultado matlab

cn =

  Columns 1 through 23

     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1

  Columns 24 through 46

     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     0

  Columns 47 through 69

     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1

  Columns 70 through 92

     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1

  Columns 93 through 115

     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     1

  Columns 116 through 138

     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0

  Columns 139 through 161

     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0

  Columns 162 through 184

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     0

  Columns 185 through 207

     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0

  Columns 208 through 230

     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0

  Columns 231 through 253

     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1

  Columns 254 through 276

     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0

  Columns 277 through 299

     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

  Columns 300 through 322

     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     1

  Columns 323 through 345

     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0

  Columns 346 through 368

     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0

  Columns 369 through 391

     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0

  Columns 392 through 414

     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1

  Columns 415 through 437

     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0

  Columns 438 through 460

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1

  Columns 461 through 483

     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1

  Columns 484 through 506

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1

  Columns 507 through 529

     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1

  Columns 530 through 552

     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0

  Columns 553 through 575

     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1

  Columns 576 through 598

     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1

  Columns 599 through 621

     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1

  Columns 622 through 644

     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1

  Columns 645 through 667

     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0

  Columns 668 through 690

     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

  Columns 691 through 713

     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

  Columns 714 through 736

     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     1

  Columns 737 through 759

     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1

  Columns 760 through 768

     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1
```

No python tenho assim a função convertida

```
cn=np.arange(sn,n_rep).reshape(1)
```

resultado

```
cn=np.arange(sn,n_rep).reshape(1)

TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

como poderei realizar da mesma forma que o matlab, o que tenho de mudar?

Comment: Não é por nada, mas colocar a matriz inteira desta forma não ajuda em muita coisa. Colocar as dimensões relevantes para o problema sim.
Caso seja necessário esta data (não me parece, mas...), coloque o setting `numeric display` na opcão `compact`, assim vc fica apenas com linhas de texto relevantes.

Comment: Explicar o que você quer fazer ajuda muito tb! Como fluente em matlab e python eu sei *exatamente* o que você quer fazer, mas mostrar esforco em fazer uma questão clara ajuda o site e aos outros usuários. Mostra que você tentou resolver, não apenas está querendo que alguém faca o seu trabalho.

Comment: em que sitio coloco setting numeric display?no matlab?

Comment: e como faço ou que função faz no python?